# VBA for excel and word to print barcode labels

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I wrote this code but it doesn't work. I am asking help with the Word section.
I have two problems: I am not able to generate a new page for each excel cell and the code128 is not vertically and horizontally center-aligned.

```
    Sub CreateBarcode4()
    ' Declare variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wd As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim barcode As Object
    Dim text As String
    
    ' Set the Excel sheet to read values from
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Create a new Word document
    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wd.Visible = True
    Set doc = wd.Documents.Add
    
    ' Set the page format to 10cm x 5cm
    With doc.PageSetup
        .PaperSize = wdPaperCustom
        .PageWidth = CentimetersToPoints(10)
        .PageHeight = CentimetersToPoints(5)
        .Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
        .VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalCenter 'Added to vertically align the content of the page
    End With
    
    ' Set the range to read values from
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    
    ' For each non-empty cell in the range
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            ' Insert a new page in the Word document
            doc.Range.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
            ' Add the text as the result of the field
            text = "DisplayBarcode " & Chr(34) & cell.Value & Chr(34) & " CODE128 \t"
            ' Add the field to the end of the document
            doc.Fields.Add Range:=doc.Range(doc.Range.End - 1), Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:=text, PreserveFormatting:=False
            ' Modify the alignment
            doc.Paragraphs(doc.Paragraphs.Count).Alignment = 1 ' wdAlignParagraphCenter
            ' Modify to hide field codes
            wd.ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

A screencapture:

[image]

Comment: Most obvious problem is that you haven’t set the page margins.

Comment: So why don't you use mailmerge? No code required.

Answer (score 1):

- Your `TopMargin` is too large.
- Inserting a page break is not necessary if you choose the proper page setup.
- `wd.Selection.EndKey wdStory` move the insert point to the end of doc. It's ready for inserting the next bar code.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Selection.EndKey method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.endkey?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158663161)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [PageSetup.TopMargin property (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.pagesetup.topmargin?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158400612)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit
   Sub CreateBarcode4()
    ' Declare variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wd As Object
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim barcode As Object
    Dim text As String
    ' Set the Excel sheet to read values from
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' Create a new Word document
    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
'    Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    wd.Visible = True
    Set doc = wd.Documents.Add
    ' Set the page format to 10cm x 5cm
    With doc.PageSetup
        .PaperSize = wdPaperCustom
        .TopMargin = 36 ' modify as needed
        .BottomMargin = 36
        .PageWidth = CentimetersToPoints(10)
        .PageHeight = CentimetersToPoints(5)
'        .Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
        .VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalCenter 'Added to vertically align the content of the page
    End With
    ' Set the range to read values from
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    ' For each non-empty cell in the range
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            ' Add the text as the result of the field
            text = "DisplayBarcode " & Chr(34) & cell.Value & Chr(34) & " CODE128 \t"
            ' Add the field to the end of the document
            doc.Fields.Add Range:=doc.Range(doc.Range.End - 1), Type:=wdFieldEmpty, text:=text, PreserveFormatting:=False
            ' Modify the alignment
            doc.Paragraphs(doc.Paragraphs.Count).Alignment = 1 ' wdAlignParagraphCenter
            ' Modify to hide field codes
            wd.ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False
            wd.Selection.EndKey wdStory
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

[image]